# Why the docker image size increases every time commiting the container?

Tags: docker, oracle-xe

I have created the Oracle XE 11g database image by using its Docker files from github. the image originally is 1.33 GB. After creating an schema and inserting the data the container size is about 2.5 GB. I need to create images in specific time points from my container. I do not want to use dockerfile to run all scripts and create the database from base every time I need it. The problem is that every time I commit the container, even without any change (for testing the behavior) the docker adds a copy of original image of size 1.33 and the size increases. why the docker do this?. Is it possible to prevent this size increases?

The first image has the following layers

```
C:>docker history oracle-xe
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
09dac6d187f9        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE2         1.33GB
84f67c51acff        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "exec…   0B
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$PWD_FILE          557kB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE          1.32GB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 1521 8080             0B
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c yum -y install unzip libaio bc in…   700MB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY multi:7301521b1b0c1e6…   316MB
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/u01/app/oracle/…   0B
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/…   0B
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER Gerald Venzl <…   0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:ec6faaeaeb57818c0…   118MB
<missing>           12 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER Oracle Linux P…   0B
```

After no changes and committing the container the new images has the following layers:

```
C:>docker history oracle-xe-commit
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
63f763341c07        19 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE2         1.33GB
09dac6d187f9        About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE2         1.33GB
84f67c51acff        3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "exec…   0B
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$PWD_FILE          557kB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c exec $ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE          1.32GB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 1521 8080             0B
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c yum -y install unzip libaio bc in…   700MB
<missing>           3 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY multi:7301521b1b0c1e6…   316MB
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/u01/app/oracle/…   0B
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/…   0B
<missing>           7 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER Gerald Venzl <…   0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:ec6faaeaeb57818c0…   118MB
<missing>           12 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER Oracle Linux P…   0B
```

Comment: Every commit adds a new layer to the image. Its size depends on the changes that were made. So with no changes the size increase will be small but not zero. You can check with `docker diff` before the commit which changes were done.

Comment: But as the commands show docker added 1.33 GB after commiting the container with no changes. Every time I repeat this It adds 1.33 again

Comment: Did you check the changes? What is `$ORACLE_BASE/$RUN_FILE2` doing?

Comment: The ```docker diff``` shows that some oracle files have been added or changes. for example: ```A /u01/app/oracle/oradiag_oracle/diag/clients/user_oracle/host_93295161_8``` and the ```$RUN_FILE2``` has a command to auto start the XE database while starting the container

Comment: So here you have why the size increases.